# Why did Australian Labor MP Khalil Eideh get denied entry to the USA?

Tags: united-states, immigration, australia, alp

[Khalil Eideh](http://www.parliament.vic.gov.au/members/details/1627-khalil-eideh) is an Australian State (Victoria) Member of Parliament who was on an official trip studying drug policy and injecting rooms. When the group was to travel from Canada to the USA he was denied entry. This [article](http://www.theage.com.au/victoria/labor-mp-khalil-eideh-denied-entry-to-the-us-20170728-gxkjtd.html) says that he was denied entry but does not give any specific reason.

The article says he was granted an "Official Visa" for the trip and being a member of parliament he is only a citizen in Australia.

The are possible reasons to assume that the denial (travel bans, religion, etc) occurred that could be correct or incorrect. I would like to know the official reason

Comment: We may not get a definitive answer, since individual decisions are not normally made public.

Comment: Um. Drug policy and injecting rooms. Something tells me AG Sessions isn't quite on board with that stuff. [Just a wee bit](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/447677/jeff-sessions-sentencing-war-drugs-congress-should-change-law).

Comment: Note that there is no requirement to renounce dual citizenship to stand for election to state parliament: that constitutional requirement only applies to federal parliament.

Answer (score 2):

One can only assume until the administration comes up with an official reason.

[This article](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2017/jul/28/disbelieving-australian-politician-on-official-study-trip-denied-entry-to-us) offers a few potential hints in the meanwhile:

> Eideh was born in Tripoli in Lebanon to Syrian parents who follow the Alawite Islamic faith. [...]
>
> It’s understood Mr Eideh has also visited Syria.

Maybe an overzealous public servant thought it should fall under the US' Muslim Ban.

Comment: This answer would be better if it didn't include the unsubstantiated assertion about a "muslim ban".

Comment: @Deolater He's a European, what do you expect?